# Nextjs 13 Custom <link> tag in head

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

My goal is to add a Safari pinned tab style in Nextjs13 app. The following tag should appear in `<head>` section:

```html
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#325758"/>
```

`Metadata.other` doesn't work, because it creates `<meta>` tag, `Metadata.icons.other` on the other hand doesn't allow custom `color` attribute.

Maybe there is a convenient way to add a completely custom head tag and avoid dealing with Nextjs types?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it's simple. Along with exported `Metadata` object you still can use regular `<head>` and `<link>` tags with any content in JSX returned by the layout component.

Comment: Hm, the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts#modifying-head) explicitly advise against adding a `<head>` tag to the root layout. But I also can't find any suggestion there on how to add custom tags to the HTML header 

Answer (score 1):

Currently on Next.js 14, You can use `Metadata.icons` in this way by specify it one by one:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Web title",
  description: "Web description",
  icons: {
    icon: [
      {
        rel: "mask-icon",
        url: "/safari-pinned-tab.svg",
        color: "#ff6f00",
      },
      {
        rel: "apple-touch-icon",
        sizes: "180x180",
        url: "/apple-touch-icon.png",
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

or with `Metadata.icons.other`:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: "Web title",
  description: "Web description",
  icons: {
    icon: "/icon.png",
    shortcut: "/shortcut-icon.png",
    apple: "/apple-icon.png",
    other: {
      rel: "custom",
      url: "/path/custom-url.png",
      color: "#ffffff",
      sizes: "128x128",
    },
  },
};
```

based on [`metadata-types.d.ts`](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/51fec997f7a8b213031d60fc15cefcbe142afb7c/packages/next/src/lib/metadata/types/metadata-types.ts#L99C11-L99C11):

```
export type IconDescriptor = {
    url: string | URL;
    type?: string;
    sizes?: string;
    color?: string;
    /** defaults to rel="icon" unless superseded by Icons map */
    rel?: string;
    media?: string;
    /**
     * @see https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/fetchPriority
     */
    fetchPriority?: 'high' | 'low' | 'auto';
};
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).